# write special characters using a custom font with itext java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, custom-font

I am adding a custom font to `itext` like so:

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
BaseFont customfont = BaseFont.createFont("/assets/fonts/GillSans-SemiBold.ttf", BaseFont.CP1257, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

now this it does fine but when i try to print accented characters like `Matemática` it prints `?`
Any thoughts on how to print accented characters with `gilSans SemiBold` font?

Comment: Codepage 1257 does [not contain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195059.aspx) the character `á`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change the second parameter in this line:

```
BaseFont customfont = BaseFont.createFont(
    "/assets/fonts/GillSans-SemiBold.ttf",
    BaseFont.CP1257, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Make it:

```
BaseFont customfont = BaseFont.createFont(
    "/assets/fonts/GillSans-SemiBold.ttf",
    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

When using `CP1257`, you create a *simple font* that contains only 256 characters. You are using characters that aren't a part of those 256 characters. You need to create a composite font that accepts UNICODE characters. As you are using a horizontal writing system, use `IDENTITY_H` as "encoding".